# Deprivatized email repository

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, privacy

I need to create a repository of some historical emails for employee training purpose. Sensitive information in those emails should be removed, such as customers' email address and their names. Is their a way to implement this in office 365? Built-in methods would be preferred but if there isn't any, custom implementation is also acceptable. I would also want to use Azure Rights Management to prevent copy/paste/print.

DLP won't process existing mails and its rules are limited / not customizable.

Comment: To do this perfectly would require a full AI.

Comment: I don't understand. All the rules to remove sensitive info will be provided.

Comment: Maybe I can create a sharepoint site for email display? Just some wild thoughts.